# Scan and listen to events from Bluetooth devices in background with flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background-process, foreground-service

I want to set up a mobile application with flutter which also runs in the background. this application allows you to scan Bluetooth devices and listen to events to launch notification and/or start a ringtone.
I managed to do all this and it works very well with the flutter_blue plugin. But my problem is that the application has to keep running in the background.

I came here to seek help.

The app does exactly what this app does https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antilost.app3&hl=fr&gl=US

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do it.

1. All you have to do that is write a native code in JAVA/Kotlin for android and obc-c/swift for ios.

The best place to start with this is [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab)

If you just follow the above link then you will be able to code MethodChannel and EventChannel, which will be useful to communicate between flutter and native code. So, If you are good at the native side then it won't be big deal for you.

```
// For example,  if you want to start service in android 

// we write
//rest of the activity code
onCreate(){
  startBluetoothService(); 
}


startBluetoothService(){
//your code
}
//then, For the flutter

// Flutter side 

MessageChannel msgChannel=MessageChannel("MyChannel");
msgChannel.invokeMethode("startBluetoothService");

// Native side

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "MyChannel";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
  super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
           if (call.method.equals("startBluetoothService")) {
              int response = startBluetoothService();

//then you can return the result based on the your code execution
              if (response != -1) {
                result.success(response);
              } else {
                result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Error while starting service.", null);
              }
            } else {
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        );
  }
}
```

same as above you can write the code for the iOS side.

2. Second way is to write your own plugin for that you can take inspiration from [alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) or [Background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location) plugins.

I hope it helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is very useful.
I know how to communicate the flutter code with the native code I made a lot of applications like that. However, what I want is that the scan also works in the background.

So if I understand what you mean I have to create a forground service on the android side to have the notification bar.
But the problem is, I don't know where I should write the code for the background scan and also how to keep the connection with bluetooth devices in the background.
Thank you.

Comment: Where means you can write code into your native Bluetooth foreground service where you can trigger your start and stop methods. I haven't made with bluetooth but I made it with location and it works fine as the background location service plugin was not developed at that time. So to start and stop you can use method Channel and to stream the scan results you can use an event channel (for me I was sending new locations). you can handle this data in the onListen/onData method of the event channel's stream. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you but I don't quite understand what you mean. I am not an android expert there are some things that I still don't understand.
Can you provide me with some sample code so I can see what you mean?
That way I would understand better.
Thanks again.

Comment: I am sorry if my explanation is a little confusing but surely you can check out this link which will lead you to the demo: http://gestyy.com/erHe9h. Thanks Hope this will help you to understand better.